# Data-Bound Combobox sometimes returning Value other than the one selected as displaymember

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

This is all the code related to the combox.

```
string SelectedDealer = Dealers.SelectedValue.ToString();
this.Dealers.DataSource = this.dealersBindingSource;
this.Dealers.DisplayMember = "DealerName";
this.Dealers.ValueMember = "DealerName";
```

The Dealers table has only two columns. What happens is, sometimes(one or two times/ application run) the

```
Dealers.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

returns the value of the other data-member,letsay Dealer-Id; right,that is Pretty weird.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing order of lines, who knows, it may help :) Maybe Combobox sets something default to ValueMember after setting its datasource if ValueMember is not previously set.

```
this.Dealers.DisplayMember = "DealerName";
this.Dealers.ValueMember = "DealerName";
this.Dealers.DataSource = this.dealersBindingSource;
string SelectedDealer = Dealers.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Also check if something is in fact selected in your combobox: SelectedIndex of combobox souldn't be -1 (SelectedValue then may be unspecified, although it should throw NullPointerException)

Comment: The code is basically visual studio-generated and is in good order and the SelectedDealer string comes in the end,thanks for your concern though :)